# IConfiguration does not contain a definition for Get() (EF7, vNext)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm fiddling with EntityFramework 7 and ASP.NET 5/vNext. I follow [this tutorial](http://mvc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/mvc-with-entity-framework.html). However I run into an issue when I try to get the connection string from the config.json file:

`'IConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'Get' and no extension method 'Get' accepting a first argument of type 'IConfiguration' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I don't think that I'm missing a reference, but here is the project.json dependencies section:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebUtilities": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Owin.Security": "3.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth": "3.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin": "2.2.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8-15186",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8-15078",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8-15086"
  }
```

Here is the code causing the issue (in Startup.cs):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddEntityFramework()
                    .AddSqlServer()
                    .AddDbContext<RibandelleDbContext>(options =>
                    {
                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get("Data:ConnectionString"));
                    });            
            }
```

The `Configuration.Get("Data:ConnectionString")` bit returns the error above. I've done my best to compare the code to the documentation samples, and it seems fairly identical to me. I can't figure out where the Get() method comes from.

How can I properly figure out what I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like `IConfiguration.Get()` was removed in beta5. Not sure if this is the best option, but you should be able to use the indexer to access the setting. Something like this:

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<RibandelleDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"]);
    });
```

Comment: Ah, good! I had no idea we could use it like that. For future reference, how could I have figured that out myself?

Comment: I feel your pain. It's tough keeping up with all the API changes as the code is being developed. I guess that's the price we pay for working with beta software - even the docs can't keep up with the current state of the code. To answer your question, I found this solution by looking at the source for IConfiguration.cs on github.

Answer (score 2):

**IConfiguration** should have the method `string Get(string key)` in `"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta6"` package

I'm not sure in beta5 though.

I have just tested with the latest version:

```
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8-15562"
```

and it has been removed from there as well.

As per Peter's comment you can access the json properties in an indexed way.

Example:

public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
                        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

    string test = Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"]; //this reads the property
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //services.AddMvc();

    services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<RibandelleDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:ConnectionString"]);
        });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
}
```

}

assuming that you have a `config.json` file with the Connection String under Data like below:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=.;Database=Your_Database_Name;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is it exactly, but if you analyze the [sample application](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/mvc/tutorials/mvc-with-entity-framework/sample/src/ContosoBooks/Startup.cs) for that article, you can see what using statements you need for that file.

```
using ContosoBooks.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Framework.Logging;
using Microsoft.Framework.Runtime;
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, perhaps analyzing the sample will.

Comment: My code has the same using statements (except the ContosoBooks.Models of course), sorry for not posting this in the question description.

Answer (score 0):

When I was getting similar errors I just removed `dnxcore50` from frameworks - some of the compile errors referenced `dnxcore50` .

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "RRStore.EF": "1.0.0-*"
    }
  },
  "dnxcore50": { }
},
```